# Using conditional for float position

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a document that I will print in two different page sizes (A5, A4).
Some figures are always printed on a separate page, regardless of the page size.
This is fine when printing in A5, but when printing in A4 there is too much whitespace around them.
If I force the top position with `\begin{figure}[t]`, it works in A4, but the figure gets pushed at the end of the chapter in A5.

I want to specify the float position as a conditional, something like this

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{a4}
\togglefalse{a4}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[\iftoggle{a4}{t}{p}]
Figure
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, this raises an error

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `\'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ->\errmessage  LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `\reserved@a '.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help\@err@                                                                   

l.7 \begin{figure}[\iftoggle{a4}{t}{p}]

Option `\' ignored and `p' used.
```

I know I can wrap the entire figure twice in a `\iftoggle{a4}{\begin{figure}[t]...}{\begin{figure}[p]...}` command, specifying different positions, but I want to avoid duplicating code.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Also, you don't need to wrap the _entire_ figure in the conditional, just the `\begin{figure}[...]`is enough: `\iftoggle{a4}{\begin{figure}[t]}{\begin{figure}[p]}`.

Comment: This somehow feels wrong, but it works quite well. I did not think it was possible to "split" environments like that. You should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: I added that and an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `latex.ltx` the float position specifier is no expanded, thus it doesn't work. However, it can be easily patched to `\edef` the argument, so the `\iftoggle` (which is expandable) gives the correct result:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@xfloat
  {\def\@fps{#2}}
  {\edef\@fps{#2}}
  {}{\ERROR! Failed to patch.}
\makeatother

\newtoggle{a4}
\togglefalse{a4}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[\iftoggle{a4}{t}{p}]
Figure
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Beware: There are many packages which access this part of the LaTeX kernel, so this solution might break something.

---

With a little code repetition you can do:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{a4}
\togglefalse{a4}
\begin{document}
\iftoggle{a4}
 {\begin{figure}[t]}%
 {\begin{figure}[p]}% < Don't forget this % here
    Figure
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This one works because `\begin{environment}` essentially does `\begingroup\environment`, which is perfectly fine to be put in a conditional like that.